# Setting inertia for a whole robot

Tags: ros, quadcopter, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am trying to model a quadrotor, i have the .model file from an old implementation in gazebo but i need to rewrite it as a .urdf to be used in ROS. My problem is that rather then setting the inertia for each link i would like to set it for the whole robot (in fact the controller will consider the quadrotor as a unique body). Is it possible somehow?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11017/setting-inertia-for-a-whole-robot/) by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

...moving my comment here as I ran out of room :)

If the links are connected via fixed joints, you should be able to assign inertia to any one of the fixed-joint-connected links and set the rest of the links inertia to some very small numbers (1e-6).  As of diamondback, inertia of fix-joint-connected links are lumped into their parent.  In general, 0 inertia will not work as the urdf2gazebo parser will ignore the link and break the kinematic chain.

On the other hand, non-fixed-joint-connected links with inertia close to 0 might make your dynamics unstable.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erpa](https://answers.ros.org/users/995/erpa/) on 2011-08-29**:
thanks a lot for your help